# Selenium cropping image using webdriver actions

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, crop

I have a modal box that appears which holds an image that I wish to crop using Selenium.

[image]

```
<div class="crop" style="width: 380px; height: 204px; position: absolute; top: -2px; left: -2px; z-index: 280; cursor: crosshair;"></div>
```

I tried using Actions from other attempts I've seen:

```
Actions crop = new Actions(driver);
crop.dragAndDropBy(cropTracker, 30,220).perform();
```

where cropTracker is the correct xpath for the WebElement ie. crop

What I see on execution is that the modal just blinks momentarily rather than performing the crop drag as shown in the image attached; not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try This !

```
Action crop = new Actions(driver);
crop.clickAndHold(cropTracker).moveByOffset(30, 50).release().build().perform();
/*it will first click and Hold the cropTracker Element, after that it will move to the 
30px right side and 50px upward.*/
```

Comment: I tried this but the crop element just blinks on executing; if I break this up as illustrated by @Stas in the next thread then after release().perform() the crop element blinks and doesn't release the crop element.

Answer (score 0):

In ours custumized framework we using something like:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        action.ClickAndHold(elementToDrag);
        action.MoveToElement(elementToDropOn, 5, 5);
        action.Perform();
        Thread.Sleep(250); //note the sleep here. magic sleep.
        action.Release(elementToDropOn);
        action.Perform();
```

Comment: I tried this but the release event/action for some reason isn't getting triggered.